# How to cotrol 3D animation (collada file) by seek bar (or timeline)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to control my 3D animation (collada) by seek bar(like Video player).
But I can't figure out how to do. I use three.js and dat.gui.js.
My code is below.

```js
<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('../assets/models/monster.dae', function (collada) {

            var child = collada.skins[0];
            scene.add(child);

            var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
            animation.play();

            // position the mesh
            child.scale.set(0.15, 0.15, 0.15);
            child.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
            child.position.x = -100;
            child.position.y = -60;
        });


        render();


        function render() {
            stats.update();

        
                var delta = clock.getDelta();
                THREE.AnimationHandler.update(delta);
            
            
            orbit.update()
            // render using requestAnimationFrame
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

      
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

please tell me how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed my code
I used dat.gui
let controls = new function () {
this.seekBar = 0 }
gui.add(controls, 'seekBar', 0, 0.1)

////in function render////
delta = controls.seekBar

Comment: What version of threejs is this? It looks older, the newer version of ColladaLoader works differently... may want to try a recent version and see the animation docs.

Comment: is this resolved ?